# Angular material date picker sending date 1 day before and how to use moment with Angular material datepicker

Tags: angular, angular-material, momentjs, angular-material2

I am using angular material date picker but when I am sending date to my backend. It is sending date which is 1 day before. So if I select 6th February then while sending to the backend it selects 5th Feb. My date value shown in json console as "treatmentDate":"2021-02-05T18:30:00.000Z"

code for Datepicker

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                    <mat-label>Choose Treatment Date</mat-label>
                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp3" formControlName="treatmentDate" required>
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp3"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #dp3 disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>
```

Post Model

```
 let postPatientInformation: PostTreatmentInformationModel = {
      id: treatmentInformationFormData.id,
      title : treatmentInformationFormData.treatmentTitle,
      summary: treatmentInformationFormData.treatmentSummary,
      patientId: this.treatmentInformation.patientId,
      treatmentDate: this.formatDate(treatmentInformationFormData.treatmentDate),
      treatmentFiles: this.treatmentFiles == null ? null : this.treatmentFiles
    };
    console.log("In post treatment", JSON.stringify(postPatientInformation));
```

Issue solved by formatting the date to remove offset

```
 var offsetMs = treatmentDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
return new Date(treatmentDate.getTime() - offsetMs);
```

How to fix this issue? Also, after researching I found out that this issue is related to formatting and many suggest to use moment with angular material datepicker. But I do not know how to use it.

Comment: Please check the answer and let me know.

Comment: add your formatDate() function

Comment: I have not written it as I was trying somethings with moment if anything works but at the moment just returning the same value. Even without formatDate function it is the same

Comment: Issue solved by adding a format function.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solution for you. I am using `ReavitveForm` to solve your problem. Here is my code given below =>
**HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                    <mat-label>Choose Treatment Date</mat-label>
                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp3" formControlName="treatmentDate" required>
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp3"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #dp3 disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
 </mat-form-field>

</form>

<br><span>Selected Treatment date:</span> {{selectedTreatmentDate}}
```

**TS:**

```
export class DatepickerOverviewExample {
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder) {
      this.form = fb.group({
        treatmentDate:this.treatmentDate
      });
     
       this.treatmentDate.valueChanges.subscribe((v) => {
        this.selectedTreatmentDate = v;
      })
    }
  form: FormGroup;
  treatmentDate= new FormControl(new Date());
  selectedTreatmentDate: Date;
}
```

**NOTE:** I have created a stackblitz demo for you. Please Check the link of [Stackblitz Demo Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-datepicker-work-peq7ef?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts)

Comment: Even  I am getting correct value after changing. When I am binding my formdata value to my post model variable it is showing day as one day before to the chosen date

Comment: I have modified the code to add my post model. In my console it is showing wrong value

Comment: Did you tried with `this.treatmentDate.valueChanges.subscribe((v) =>{this.selectedTreatmentDate = v;})`? please try it in my way once in your environment. and let me know.

Comment: It is not working in my environment. I checked on Stack overflow many developers  faced this issue but didn't find any concrete working solution

Comment: But It is working in my environment and stackblitz.too. It is really unfortunate . :(

Comment: Found a solution added  var offsetMs = treatmentDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
return new Date(treatmentDate.getTime() - offsetMs); as formatting option

Comment: Great Work @AjinkyaGadgil